# Phantom Js, CasperJs External scripts not evaluating properly

Tags: javascript, server-side, phantomjs, casperjs

Interesting issue here, Im using injectJs to load an external file (site.js) into my phantomJs/CasperJs script. Its loading fine, but the functions are not evaluating and are returning as strings.

Here is site.js:

```
var site = function(){
     this.getName = function(){
         return 'this is a name';
     }
}
```

Here's my phantom.js script:

```
casper.start();

casper.then(function(){
    phantom.injectJs('/path/to/site.js');
    mysite = new site(casper);
    name = mysite.getName;
    this.echo(name);

});
```

I would expect the console to print out: 'this is a name',
But instead it prints out: 'function(){ this.getName = function(){ return 'this is a name'; }}'

I tried eval()ing it as well to no avail (eval?).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `()`:

```
name = mysite.getName();
```

Comment: Geez, I feel dumb... Thanks.

Comment: Np, it happens to all of us sometimes ;)